# Stripe android, created PaymentIntent on server and confirm it on Android, but created requires_payment_method error

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I am following the doc: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#android

On server side:

1. Created `PaymentIntentCreateParams`, I set the currency and amount on this object
2. Created the `PaymentIntent` using `PaymentIntentCreateParams`
3. the `clientSecretKey` is sent to the client (android)

On client side:

1. Getting the `PaymentMethodCreateParams` from the `CardMultilineWidget`
2. Create a `ConfirmPaymentIntentParams` using the `PaymentMethodCreateParams` and `clientSecretKey`
3. Using the `stripe` object to `confirmPayment`

Here is the payment associated with this transaction:

[image]

Obviously, the payment didn't go through and I don't understand why and how I am getting this status, my payment method is what is on the `CardMultilineWidget` isn't?

How do I set the payment method on the `PaymentIntent`?

Server

```
 @PostMapping("/api/payment")
    @ResponseBody
    public String startPay(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers,
                           @RequestParam(name = "currency") String currency,
                           @RequestParam(name = "name") String name) throws Exception{

        PaymentBody paymentBody = new PaymentBody(currency, name);

        PaymentIntentCreateParams createParams = new PaymentIntentCreateParams.Builder()
                .setCurrency(paymentBody.getCurrency())
                .setAmount(100000L)
                .addPaymentMethodType("card")
                .build();

        PaymentIntent intent = PaymentIntent.create(createParams);

        Gson gson = new Gson().newBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(intent));

        PaymentResponse paymentResponse = new PaymentResponse(ApiKey.PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
                intent.getClientSecret(),
                intent.getId(),
                intent.getStatus());

        return gson.toJson(paymentResponse);
    }
```

Client:

```
 @Override
    public void onPayClicked() {

        mStripeApi.requestPaymentIntent("USD", "Name").enqueue(new Callback<PaymentResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PaymentResponse> call, Response<PaymentResponse> response) {

                PaymentMethodCreateParams paymentMethodCreateParams = mViewMvc.getCardDetails();

                if(paymentMethodCreateParams == null) {
                    return;
                }

                mViewMvc.setResponse(response.body().getResponse());

                ConfirmPaymentIntentParams confirmPaymentIntentParams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.
                        createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(paymentMethodCreateParams, response.body().getClientSecret());

                mStripe.confirmPayment(mFragmentActivity, confirmPaymentIntentParams);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PaymentResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope, still haven't figured it out

Comment: I have the same issue. I believe the payment method should be the Stripe Token generated when the customer sets the payment details, but I'm not sure.